# How to call a function after quickfix windows was opened by calling make

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm writing a small plugin to work with [meson](https://mesonbuild.com): I use the `makeprg` variable to set up the command, so I can benefit from the quickfix window. After I set the variable I call make and after that I want to call another local function:

```
  function s:LinkCompilationDatabase()
    ...
  endfunction

  function s:MesonSetup() abort
    let &makeprg = 'meson setup builddir'
    silent make|redraw!

    s:LinkCompilationDatabase()
  endfunction
```

It fails with this error:

```
  Error detected while processing function <SNR>22_MesonSetup:
  line   xx:
  E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

It doesn't make any difference if the make step has an error or not.

How do I call a function after `make`?

Comment: `let &make` I suppose you want [`makeprg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'makeprg'), not `make`?

Comment: @phd Correct. Changed it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:call` to call a function, and `:let` to store a function result/an expression.